# Deleting appointment from someone else's calendar

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have Access VBA code that creates appointments in three tech colleagues' calendars.

```vb
If vbYes = MsgBox("Send Calendar Appointments?", vbYesNo) Then
    Dim outMail As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Set outMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    outMail.Subject = "Lab Booking - " & FullName & " - for date " & Forms!frmLabSession_edit!BookingDate
    outMail.Mileage = Me.LabBooking_ID
    outMail.Location = Forms!frmLabSession_edit!frm_qryLabsBookedPerBooking_subform!RoomNo
    outMail.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
    outMail.Start = BookingDate & " " & TimeFrom
    outMail.End = BookingDate & " " & TimeTo
    outMail.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 21600
    outMail.RequiredAttendees = "Person1@tees.ac.uk; Person2@tees.ac.uk; Person3@tees.ac.uk" & Me.txtCCList
    outMail.Body = "You have received this notification with a 15 days countdown to cover periods of leave when you may not have received initial notification." & Chr$(13) & _
      Chr$(13) & Me.Notes
    outMail.Attachments.Add FileName
    outMail.Send
    Set outMail = Nothing
End If
```

I have code for deleting appointments based on the subject line, but I can't figure out how to add recipients - the other calendar users - it only removes it from *my* calendar.

```vb
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim lngDeletedAppointements As Long
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strLocation As String
Dim dteStartDate As Date
    
'******************************** Set Criteria for DELETION here ********************************
strSubject = "Lab Booking - " & FullName & " - for date " & Forms!frmLabSession_edit!BookingDate
strLocation = Forms!frmLabSession_edit!frm_qryLabsBookedPerBooking_subform!RoomNo
dteStartDate = BookingDate
'************************************************************************************************
    
Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    
For Each objAppointment In objFolder.Items
    If objAppointment.Subject = strSubject And objAppointment.Location = strLocation And _
      objAppointment.Start > dteStartDate Then
        objAppointment.Delete
        lngDeletedAppointements = lngDeletedAppointements + 1
    End If
Next
    
MsgBox lngDeletedAppointements & " appointment(s) DELETED.", vbInformation, "DETETE Appointments"
```

How do I declare or state in the code the attendees' calendars to remove the item from, as the top code does to send them?

I have delete rights to their calendars. I can go into their calendars and delete the appointment, so shouldn't be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following sequence of action to cancel the meeting and notify attendees:

```
AppointmentItem.MeetingStatus = olMeetingCanceled
AppointmentItem.Save
AppointmentItem.Send
AppointmentItem.Delete
```

Just set the meeting canceled status which stands for - the scheduled meeting has been cancelled.

Comment: Fantastic - many thanks, works just right!